# How to asess the importance of variables in a logit-transformed model

Tags: regression, linear-regression, panel, logistic-regression, mlogit

My dependent variable is the share of workers on long-term contracts and I run a fixed-effects regression on the panel dataset to assess the relative importance of various variables, such as the availability of alternative jobs, unemployment, distance from a major city etc. By definition the dependent variable *share* is bounded between 0 and 1, and I use logistic transformation
logit(*share*)= log(*share* / 1 - *share*)
to move a continuous variable.
Now I have the regression coefficients for logit(*share*). How can I use them to assess the relative contribution of independent variables to explaining the variation in the original variable *share*?